# Can you add notes and save in R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

We are using a shiny app to build some tables and charts and share this with various teams. But then we also end up copying those to excel sheets/PowerPoint and then add some notes to it and share it. This is just increasing the steps for us. Is it possible on to add some notes into a shiny app that can be saved? And then anyone else who logs in can read those. Thank you.

Comment: You can use an input like [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/textAreaInput.html) for your shiny app. Then you can save the commands inside this input box by using an action button to write them into a text file maybe. Every new command can be added  to the textfile maybe with users id to determine the commander. Finally you can present those commands via  verbatimTextOutput() automatically by adressing that text file at the bottom of your graphs.

Comment: So when you say save, it will be saved in a text file or a DB may be. any idea on how to do that via shiny. Will that need the bookmarking state ?

Comment: You can trigger any function with [actionbutton](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html). Just use it to trigger `write.csv( )` etc.

Comment: If you are already using a database, and I assume you are intending these "notes" to be available the next time you look at this set of data, then I suggest setting up a simple DB table that directly references this data (some foreign key reference), some notes, and perhaps who added them and when (a timestamp). What you're asking for is a significant "feature" to be added that might be larger than the SO forum-method is designed for, but regardless we'd need to know existing structure (db, shiny, perhaps data).